# Friendly URL's with an IndexController

Tags: php, url-routing

My current router / FrontController is setup to dissect URL's in the format:

```
http://localhost/controller/method/arg1/arg2/etc...
```

However, I'm not sure how to get certain requests to default to the IndexController so that I can type:

```
http://localhost/contact
or
http://localhost/about/portfolio
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost/index/contact
or
http://localhost/index/about/portfolio
```

How is this accomplished?

```
<?php

namespace framework;

class FrontController {
    const DEFAULT_CONTROLLER = 'framework\controllers\IndexController';
    const DEFAULT_METHOD     = 'index';

    public $controller       = self::DEFAULT_CONTROLLER;
    public $method           = self::DEFAULT_METHOD;
    public $params           = array();
    public $model;
    public $view;

    function __construct() {
        $this->model = new ModelFactory();
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    // route request to the appropriate controller
    public function route() {
        // get request path
        $basePath = trim(substr(PUBLIC_PATH, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])), '/') . '/';
        $path = trim(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
        if($basePath != '/' && strpos($path, $basePath) === 0) {
            $path = substr($path, strlen($basePath));
        }

        // determine what action to take
        @list($controller, $method, $params) = explode('/', $path, 3);
        if(isset($controller, $method)) {
            $obj = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\controllers\\' . ucfirst(strtolower($controller)) . 'Controller';
            $interface = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\controllers\\' . 'InterfaceController';
            // make sure a properly implemented controller and corresponding method exists
            if(class_exists($obj) && method_exists($obj, $method) && in_array($interface, class_implements($obj))) {
                $this->controller = $obj;
                $this->method = $method;

                if(isset($params)) {
                    $this->params = explode('/', $params);
                }
            }
        }
        // make sure we have the appropriate number of arguments
        $args = new \ReflectionMethod($this->controller, $this->method);
        $totalArgs = count($this->params);
        if($totalArgs >= $args->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() && $totalArgs <= $args->getNumberOfParameters()) {
            call_user_func_array(array(new $this->controller, $this->method), $this->params);
        } else {
            $this->view->load('404');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: @ThiefMaster This is for a custom framework I'm building to learn.

Comment: Well without knowing your routing code it's pretty hard to help you

Comment: @ThiefMaster if you could explain the gist of how it works with pseudo-code, or even demonstrating the principle with an established framework, that would be really helpful. My current code isn't much more than: `@list($controller, $method, $params) = explode('/', $path, 3);`

Comment: Never suppress errors, where it is not necessary. Also, you should look into regexp-based routing mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your URLs by one of two methods:

**Establish the controllers the way your routing defines them**

example.com/contact => Have a "contact" controller with default or index action

example.com/about/portfolio => Have an "about" controller with a "portfolio" action

Because your currently available routing says your URL is treated like "/controller/method", there is no other way.

**Establish dynamic routing to allow multiple URLs to be handled by a single controller**

Obviously this needs a bit of configuration because one cannot know which URLs are valid and which one should be redirected to the generic controller, and which ones should not. This is somehow a replacement for any of the rewriting or redirecting solutions, but as it is handled on the PHP level, change might be easier to handle (some webserver configurations do not offer .htaccess because of performance reasons, and it generally is more effort to create these).

Your configuration input is:

1. The URL you want to be handled and
2. The controller you want the URL passed to, and it's action.

You'll end up having an array structure like this:

```
$specialRoutes = array(
    "/contact" => "IndexController::indexAction",
    "/about/portfolio" => "IndexController::indexAction"
);
```

What's missing is that this action should get the current URL passed as a parameter, or that the path parts become designated parameters within your URL schema.

All in all this approach is a lot harder to code. To get an idea, try to look at the routing of common MVC frameworks, like Symfony and Zend Framework. They offer highly configurable routing, and because of this, the routing takes place in multiple classes. The main router only reads the configuration and then passes the routing of any URL to the configured routers if a match is detected.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code snippet I'd do it like this (pseudo php code):

```
$handler = get_controller($controller);
if(!$handler && ($alias = lookup_alias($path))) {
    list($handler, $method) = $alias;
}
if(!$handler) error_404();

function lookup_alias($path) {
    foreach(ALL_CONTROLLERS as $controller) {
        if(($alias = $controller->get_alias($path))) {
            return $alias;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So basically in case there is no controller to handle a certain location you check if any controller is configured to handle the given path as an alias and if yes return that controller and the method it maps to.

Comment: +1 In this case it makes a lot more sense than a server rewrite.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I've edited my original question with more code... I don't understand your answer. Could you please provide a little more depth? Either way I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I wonder if a controller should be able to influence the routing of an URL. I think it is better to leave this to the routing process entirely.

Comment: @Sven My example is based off of [this tutorial](http://phpmaster.com/front-controller-pattern-1/). Part 2 of that tutorial creates a separate router, however I feel that is getting too complex for my needs. I'm not trying to build a robust framework with all the bells and whistles, just something simple for personal use.

Comment: @ThiefMaster would it be acceptable simply to, for example: if (firstParam is not a valid controller) { check to see if firstParam is a valid method in the index controller } ???

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rewrite in your webserver for these exceptions. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ /index/contact
RewriteRule ^about/portfolio$ /about/portfolio
```

This will allow you to have simplified URLs that map to your regular structure.

You could have a dynamic rule if you are able to precisely define what should be rewritten to /index. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /index/$1
```

Comment: Is there a more dynamic way to do it?

Comment: I think this is a really bad idea. It's usually good not to have more than one rewrite rule that maps everything to your controller. You don't want more webserver-specific stuff than necessary.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I would usually have only one generic rewrite for one word URLs. But in this case the fact that `/about/portfolio` maps to `index` is confusing. How can we know that `portfolio` is a parameter or the method?

Answer (score 1):

Try this dynamic htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index/$1 [QSA]
```

The [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag in the above rule allows you to also add a query string to the end if you want, like this:

```
http://localhost/contact?arg1=1&arg2=2
```

**EDIT:** This rule would also handle cases such as `/about/portfolio`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?(.+)?$ /index/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: How would you handle the `/about/portfolio` case?

Comment: @MathieuImbert I edited my answer; since the question mark makes part of it optional it should work in cases such as `/about/portfolio`.